# Proof $P_c(x) + xP_c(x) = 1- P_b(x)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

I have an exercise and the following sequences are given:

> $b_n := (-1)^n$ $c_n:= (-1)^{n+1}\cdot n$

I have to prove the following for the power-series that belong to these sequences:

> $P_c(x) + xP_c(x) = 1- P_b(x)$

I didn't make it very far though:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \cdot x^n+ x\cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} x^n$ = $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\cdot x^n + (-1)^{n+1}\cdot x^{n+1}$

Helps and hints are appreciated!

Comment: By "the series that belong," I assume you mean that for a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ we have $P_a(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$?

Comment: In that case, it seems you are neglecting a factor of $n$ in your expression for $P_c(x)$, it would be $P_c(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}nx^n$ no?